# How can I display images from the database

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am having problem to display the image stored in the server (/uploads) and the name of the field is stored in the database and linked with the user id.

my controllers:

```
function do_upload()
{
if($this->session->userdata('is_logged_in'))
{
$id = $this->session->userdata('id');
$config['upload_path'] = './uploads/';
$config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|jpeg|png';
$config['max_size'] = '100';
$config['max_width']  = '1024';
$config['max_height']  = '768';
$config['overwrite'] = false;
$this->load->library('upload', $config);
if ( ! $this->upload->do_upload())
{
$error = array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors());
$this->load->view("site_header");
$this->load->view("site_nav");
$this->load->view('upload_form', $error);
}else
{    
$data = $this->upload->data();
$file_array = $this->upload->data('file_name');
$profile['profile_picture'] = $file_array['file_name'];
$this->db->where('id', $id);
$this->db->update('users',  $profile);
$data['img']= base_url().'/uploads/'.$data['file_name'];
$this->load->view('upload_success', $data);
}


public function members(){
if($this->session->userdata('is_logged_in')){
   $this->load->model('loginmodel');
   $data = $this->loginmodel->getImage();
   print('/uploads/'.$data);
   $img = base_url().'/uploads/'.$data;
   $this->load->view("site_header");
   $this->load->view("site_nav");
   $this->load->view("members");
   $this->load->view("site_footer");

}else{.....
```

model

```
function getImage()
{
$id = $this->session->userdata('id');
$this->db->select("*");
$this->db->from('users');
$this->db->where('id', $id);
$query = $this->db->get();
if($query->num_rows()==0)
echo("Picture not found!");
else{
$data = $query->row_array();
return $data['profile_picture'];
 }
}
```

view:

```
<img src="<?php echo $img; ?>" border="0" width="10" height="10">
```

I am getting this errors:
A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Notice
Message: Undefined variable: img
Filename: views/members.php
Line Number: 19
" border="0" width="10" height="10">

Comment: Are you passing the img variable to the view?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pass the data to the view.

```
$data = array('img' => $img);
$this->load->view("members", $data);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your query might not return data because there might not be matches
try to use php's isset function in your view